# Same SQL query works in Heidi, doesn't via mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, request

I've got a piece of code (connection to the DB is not included):

```
$query = "SELECT ....... WHERE name='name1'";
echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

When I run the script, the `mysql_num_rows($result)` says that 0 rows were found. I copy the `$query` from my browser to the Heidi, run it, 1 row is found (as expected). Then I copy `$query` from the browser directly to the `mysql_query`, run script, 1 row is found.

If I change `name1` to some other entry, the script works well! The example of the problem name has no special characters: `Uniwersalna  praline Бордюр 2,3x60` it's a Windows-1251 encoding. The script and the database are encoded in it.

Why `mysql_query` couldn't find the row? Even our lead-dev couldn't help me...

update: moved everything to the `mysqli_*` - same result.

Comment: Please, use mysqli_* functions or PDO. MYSQL_* are deprecated.

Comment: Because, `$query` alone can not return database resource

Comment: Perhaps it's just an edit issue but that's not what `$result` is supposed to contain. I suggest you edit the question to avoid confusions.

Comment: @phpNoOb connection to the DB is established well. It's just not included. Entries with other names are found. There are just some problem names...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario thank you! It was a typo, edited!

Comment: All problematic names contain double spaces... Can `mysqli_query` delete one of them maybe?

Comment: @Kolyunya - Nope, it cannot. But rendering whitespace characters as HTML will collapse them. When you copy the SQL query to paste it into HeidiSQL make sure you do it from your browser's View Source screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the `name` from an external file. In the text editor and in the browser (even in the source code viewer) `space` characters were looking normally, but in fact they were some other special characters. They were rendered in the source code viewer of the browser normally, that's why the query executed properly in the Heidi.